# Is the quotient presheaf $\mathbb{G}_m/\mu_p$ an étale sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p > 0$. Consider the multiplicative group scheme $\mathbb{G}_m$ and its subgroup $\mu_p$, the $p$-th roots of unity. It is well known that the quotient presheaf $\mathbb{G}_m / \mu_p$ is not a sheaf in fppf topology, and its sheafification in fppf topology is representable by $\mathbb{G}_m$ via the morphism $\mathbb{G}_m \xrightarrow{\cdot \mapsto \cdot^p} \mathbb{G}_m$. However, is the quotient presheaf $\mathbb{G}_m / \mu_p$ an **étale** sheaf?

If $U \rightarrow X$ is an étale cover, I can prove the equalizer sequence $\mathbb{G}_m / \mu_p(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m / \mu_p (U) \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m / \mu_p(U\times_X U)$ is exact when X is **reduced**. In fact, if $s \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)^\times$ and $(\frac{s\otimes 1}{1\otimes s})^p = 1$, since $U\times_X U$ is again reduced we can deduce $s\otimes 1 = 1\otimes s$ hence $s\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)^\times$. However I don't know to prove the general case when $X$ is not reduced. I tried several ways to formulate an induction, but couldn't work it out.

Appreciate any hints towards a proof or a counterproof. Thank you!

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Is the quotient presheaf $\mathbb{G}_m/\mu_p$ an étale sheaf?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/321276) I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) contains very reasonable advice about cross-posting. The most important thing is probably to link both copies to each other. (Of course, you can have a look at other discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting], too.)